# Filter not working on multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I am using filter in the following way

```
$("body div header").find("*").addBack().contents().filter(function(){
    console.log(this.nodeType);
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function() {
    $(this).parent().html(this.nodeValue.replace(/abc/g, '<span class="abc">abc</span>'));
})
```

But this doesn't work as it does not add the class to the matched words. http://jsfiddle.net/hrEyC/3/

What could be wrong? How can I make this case-insensitive?

Comment: there is no **header** tag in your html as you are using it in script

Comment: Please include the relevant html in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there's no `header` in your markup, so the very first jQuery object you're trying to process is empty.

However, the whole approach is a bit wrong: different text nodes will have the same node as a parent, yet you basically rewritten this node's innerHTML each time. Actually, as most of the first-child text nodes in this example are of `'\n   '` flavor, all the other don't matter - they will be gone after the first corresponding `$(this).parent().html()` call.

What you actually should use is [**replaceWith**](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) jQuery method. For example:

```
$("body div").find("*").addBack().contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3 && /abc/i.test(this.nodeValue);
}).replaceWith(function() {
  return this.nodeValue.replace(/(abc)/g, '<span class="abc">$1</span>');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M2ZS3/). Here I trimmed the list of nodes to be processed with `replaceWith` additionally (with `/abc/.test(...)`) - to make this list as slim as possible.

To make this search case-insensitive, I've added `/i` modifier to both regexes (and used `$1` in the replacement string as well - you don't want 'ABC' to become 'abc' when highlighted).

Comment: mybad. How do I make the search case insensitive?

Comment: Updated the answer with case-insensitive example.

Comment: one last help. Help me understand the code. I want to how the chaining worked, the filter, what does $1 do etc. it will help me clear some basics and I know when to apply what when I come across it next.

Comment: Well, that's rather simple actually. With `find` and `addBack` you collect all the children of `body div` element AND the element itself. With `contents().filter()` you collect all the text nodes of these elements (that what `nodeType === 3` check does), but only if they have `abc` string within. Finally, with `replace` you wrap whatever string is given in that regex into `span`: `$1` is used to preserve the text that originally was in a string.